# Writing matrix summation in equation form

Tags: matrices, summation

In Python I can sum along a matrix axis like so

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones( (10,10) )

# now sum all rows
a_sum = a.sum(axis=0)
```

I would like to write that summation as an equation in a manuscript I am preparing.  Is there a standard notation of doing this?  I have thought about using the summation symbol (Sigma), but my concern is this will be too convoluted for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should the direct summation $\sum_{i}A_{i,j}$ be too "convoluted", one could rewrite it as, e.g., $v^\mathsf{T}.A$, where $v=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is a vector with all elements equal to $1$.